# Cómo puedo hacer que cuando presione el botón me vuelva generar un texto nuevo para el richTextBox?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código para generar un texto de manera aleatoria escogiendo un elemento de un List y lo coloca dentro del richTextBox, pero necesito que cuando se presione el botón pase por el if y genere un nuevo texto para el richTextBox.

```
  public void EscogerCita()
    {

        while (citas.Count != 0)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            index = random.Next(citas.Count);
            cita = citas[index];
            richTextBox1.Text = cita;
            citas.RemoveAt(index);   
        }
    }
```

Y aquí está el código del botón

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBtn == "Filipenses 4:13" && "Todo lo puedo en Cristo." == richTextBox1.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
            puntos = +5;
            label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
            EscogerCita();
            Btn.Visible = false;


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
            Btn.Visible = false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, debes ser más especifico. Pero según lo que logro entender, para que pase por el if simplemente `txtBtn` debe ser igual a **Filipenses 4:13** y `richTextBox1.Text` igual a **Todo lo puedo en Cristo**.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar String.Equals(string1,string2) donde string1 y string2 son los strings a comparar.

Según la página de Microsoft sobre [cómo comparar Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc165449.aspx)

> Es conveniente evitar el uso de los operadores == y != al comparar cadenas